# I'm completely helpless using a downloaded colour palette in R

Tags: r, colors

today I downloaded the *ggsci* colour palette in R because I want a diagramme to be displayed in, let's say, the NEJM colours.

Thing is, after installing the package and adding it to the library, I have not the slightest clue how to use it. No matter what I try, the programme always indicates different kinds of errors which I don't know how to fix. Could someone who's familiar with using these palettes just explain what I have to do *in general*, i.e. what parameters I have to insert in here:

```
barplot(Z,beside=TRUE,names=c("a","b","c"),col = ??????? )
```

Comment: Read the section of the `ggsci` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsci/vignettes/ggsci.html) on non-ggplot graphics.

Comment: I already read this, I still don't get what I have to insert in the code to use the colours in a plot

Comment: If I type. eg. col=scale_fill_nejm(3) it doesn't work

Comment: From what I linked: "simply use the palette generator functions". Use the `pal_nejm` function like in the example from the vignette.

Comment: Can you give me an example how that's supposed to work? I do not understand which part of that code I have to use or why there's this function when I just wanna use this one specific palette

Comment: I mean, for example I don't understand why they use the parameters p1, p2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the colours like this:

```
library(ggsci)
COLS = pal_nejm()(8)
[1] "#BC3C29FF" "#0072B5FF" "#E18727FF" "#20854EFF" "#7876B1FF" "#6F99ADFF"
[7] "#FFDC91FF" "#EE4C97FF"
```

If you want to colour your bars sequentially, do:

```
barplot(1:8,col=COLS)
```

[image]

If it's like stacked, and you wanna use 2 colours for top and bottom:

```
barplot(rbind(1:8,8:1),col=COLS[1:2])
```

[image]